# How can i add blank space inside printf in c programming?

Tags: c

I want to add two blank space inside c programming print statement. I have try but it always count one single space. How can i add another one ?? If i use \t then it count 4 space as set.

```
printf("Hello  Dhaka!");
```

Comment: The question is how to print "Hello__Dhaka!"  where '_' is a space, right? and is this c or c#?

Comment: what made you think tagging java and C# would be beneficial?

Comment: Why isn't C++ tagged? I feel offended.

Comment: Just add the blank space where you want it. What's the problem ?

Comment: If you are running your code in an online compiler the problem is probably on the display side and not in your code. The output is sent to a HTML page, and in HTML consequtive whitespace characters are displayed as a single space character.

Comment: Try and use this service to test your code:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php

It will show 2 spaces

Comment: Where do you run your program? What platform ? Apparently nobody is able to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("Hello  Dhaka!");` adds 2 spaces, since it contains 2 spaces.

The problem must be related to your output. Perhaps the console uses some strange font that is not fixed-width.